# Minimum number of elements in group

Tags: group-theory

Suppose we have $G=\langle(123),(456),(14)(25)(36)\rangle$ a subgroup of $S_6$

Am I correct in saying that the minimum number of elements in $G$ equals the product of the orders of the elements of the generating set?

$|(123)|=3$, $|(456)|=3$ and $|(14)(25)(36)|=2$, so we have a minimum of $3\cdot 3 \cdot 2 = 18$ elements generated. That means $18 \leq |G|$.

Is is possible in general to multiply the orders of the different elements in the generating set of a group that is not abelian and say that is the minimum number of elements?

Comment: Duplicate of this (unanswered) question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1820823/number-of-elements-set-of-generators

Comment: The first two generators commute, so they generate a subgroup of order $9$ and hence $9$ divides $|G|$. The third generator has order $2$, so $2$ divides $|G|$. Hence $18$ divides $|G|$.

Answer (score 6):

No. Consider the group $S_4$. It is generated by the six transpositions $(12)$, $(13)$, $(14)$, $(23)$, $(24)$ and $(34)$. The order of the group is $4!$ - much less that $2^6=64$

---

I was more than a bit unhappy with the above example. Its success exploits a kind of sloppiness in the formulation of the question. Namely the fact that I used a non-minimal generating set. To wit, it suffices to use only the 2-cycles $(12)$, $(13)$ and $(14)$ to get all of $S_4$, and the OPs guess is valid for that set of generators. Therefore the above counterexample is lacking in intellectual honesty.

My suggested remedy:

1. Let's add the constraint that no proper subset of the chosen set of generators will generate the same group.
2. Consider the group of eight unit quaternions
   $$
   Q_8=\{\pm1,\pm\mathbf{i},\pm\mathbf{j},\pm\mathbf{k}\}
   $$
   defined by the relations $\mathbf{i}^2=\mathbf{j}^2=\mathbf{k}^2=-1=\mathbf{ijk}$ (together with the obvious effect of multiplication by $-1$).
   We see that $Q_8$ is not cyclic, so at least two generators are needed. However,
   $Q_8$ is generated by $\mathbf{i}$ and $\mathbf{j}$. Both of those are of order four, and $4\cdot4=16>|Q_8|$. Therefore this is an honest counterexample.
3. The counterexample of the previous bullet works even if we insist on using a set of generators such that the product of their orders is minimized. In the case of $Q_8$ **any** generating set must include at least two elements of order four.